# Mysql2 installation on Mac

Tags: osx-mavericks, mysql2

I am having problem installing mysql2 on my Mac osX maverick. Please look at the response that I got in return

```
Muhammeds-MacBook-Pro:second_app muhammedz786$ gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\"'

Building native extensions with: '--with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\"'
This could take a while...
sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/muhammedz786/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-dir="C:\mysql-connector\"

extconf failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/muhammedz786/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/muhammedz786/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.0.0-static/mysql2-0.3.14/gem_make.out
```

Please Help!

Comment: `C:\mysql-connector\ ` is a Windows path, not an OS X / Unix path.

Comment: I tried using gem install mysql2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

1. `brew install mysql`
2. `mysql_install_db`
3. `mysql.server start`
4. `gem install mysql2`

Also make sure you have XCode commandline tools installed.